# Jobs broken with SDK version 0.4.150414

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Pulled the latest SDK version (0.4.150414) from Maven, and our jobs are now failing.

We've traced it down to something with the deserialisation of a HashMap that is used in one of our classes, and which is referenced by the ParDo transformation.

Observations:

- It is broken when running both locally, and on the CDF service in the
  cloud.
- The HashMap is populated correctly before `processElement` is invoked
- Placing a breakpoint in the `processElement` method shows that the HashMap has a different object ID (which must be from deserializing the original HashMap), but it is now empty i.e. all elements have been lost.
- **We rolled back to version 0.3.150326, and it works fine with that version.**

Did anything change with the serialization/deserialization functionality in the latest version of the SDK?

Happy to send our code to the feedback email if you need it.

Comment: Sorry to hear this. A lot of things changed in 0.4 but I'm not aware of any backward-incompatible serialization changes. Can you please update the question with some sort of pseudocode describing where is your HashMap and how you use it in the pipeline?

Comment: Would it not be easier (and quicker) to just send the code over to you?

Comment: Yes, it would - let's do that. Please email dataflow-feedback@google.com.

Comment: ok, it's on it's way. We've rolled the version back to 0.3.150326 to get it working again, so you you need to do is change build.gradle to '0.4.150414' to run it against that version of the SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A change was made in the latest version to clone the DoFn when passed to a ParDo.of. This leads to better behavior if the DoFn is used multiple times, and modified in between uses.

The problem you describe would happen if the HashMap field was populated after the DoFn was passed to ParDo.of.

You can confirm this by setting a break point at ParDo.of and inspecting the state of the DoFn there. To fix this, initialize the field before invoking ParDo.of.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Fixed now. Thank you very much. However, if you haven't already done so, you should clearly document this functionality somewhere. That's a crucial piece of implementation information which may catch others out too :)